# Inputs for column length is returning unintended length

Tags: java, arrays

While working on a code for making a irregular 2D-array, I discovered a weird error while messing with different inputted values for the column. While the row works, the column length input returns either the wrong amount or a null pointer error occurs. I'm not sure what might be causing this since inputs such as ( 1 , 2 , 3) returns the correct table but (2 , 1, 3) will not. Also in a row of 4 with column inputs of (2, 3, 4, 5) returns "index out of bounds exception: 5" when there shouldn't be able to be out of bounds because of the while loop that should keep it with in reasonable range. Neither the main nor the display method seems to be saving the intended column length correctly and I can't seem to spot why.
It seems the array is set to 3 rows with column length of 1 , 2 , 3.
The output for row(3) and column(2,3,1) gives:

A:2.0

B:2.0 2.0

C:2.0 2.0 2.0

when I want is:

A:2.0 2.0

B:2.0 2.0 2.0

C:2.0

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//================================================================
public class ArrayIrreg {
//----------------------------------------------------------------
    private static Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
        char group, rLetter,letter;
        String choice;
        int sum     =  0;
        int num     = 10; // for test
        int rows    = 10;
        int columns =  8;

        //greetings
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Band of the Hour");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        // creating 2d array


        System.out.print("Please enter number of rows               : ");
        rows = Keyboard.nextInt();
        Keyboard.nextLine();

        while (rows < 0 || rows >= 10) {
            System.out.print("ERROR:Out of range, try again              : ");
            rows = Keyboard.nextInt();
            Keyboard.nextLine();
        }

        double[][] figures = new double[rows + 1][num];

        for(int t = 0; t < rows; t++) {
            rLetter = (char)((t)+(int)'A');
            System.out.print("Please enter number of positions in row " + rLetter + " : ");
            columns = Keyboard.nextInt();
            Keyboard.nextLine();

            while(columns < 0 || columns >= 8) {
                System.out.print("ERROR:Out of range, try again              : ");
                columns = Keyboard.nextInt();
                Keyboard.nextLine();
            }

            for(int j = 0; j <= columns; j++) {
                figures[j] = new double[j] ;
            }

        }

        // filling the array
        for(int row = 0; row < figures.length; ++row) {
            for(int col = 0; col < figures[row].length; ++col) {
                figures[row][col] = 2.0;
            }
        }

        // printing the array
        for(int row = 1; row < figures.length; ++row) {    
            // printing data row
            group = (char)((row-1)+(int)'A');
            System.out.print(group + " : ");

            for(int col = 0; col < figures[row].length; ++col) { 

                System.out.print(figures[row][col] + " ");
                System.out.print(" ");
                }
            System.out.print("["+","+avg(figures)+"]");
            System.out.println();
        }

        //----------MENU


        System.out.print("(A)dd, (R)emove, (P)rint,          e(X)it : ");
            choice = Keyboard.next(); 
            letter = choice.charAt(0);
            letter = Character.toUpperCase(letter);

        if(letter == 'P') {
            display(figures);
        }

    }
    public static void display(double x[][]) {
        int average, total;
        char group;

        System.out.println(" ");
        for(int row=1;row<x.length;row++) {
            group = (char)((row-1)+(int)'A');
            System.out.print(group+" : ");
            for(int column=0;column<x[row].length;column++){
                System.out.print(x[row][column]+"    ");

            }
        System.out.print("["+","+avg(x)+"]");    
        System.out.println();
        }
    } 
    public static int avg(double[][] temp) {
        int sum = 0;
        int avg = 0;

        for (int col = 0; col < temp[0].length; col++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < temp.length; row++)
                sum += temp[row][col];

                System.out.println(sum);
        }

    avg = sum / temp.length;
    return avg;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Creating 2D Array,**

Change this

```
double[][] figures = new double[rows + 1][num];
```

to

```
double[][] figures = new double[rows][num];
```

and

```
for(int j = 0; j <= columns; j++) {
    figures[j] = new double[j] ;
}
```

to

```
figures[t] = new double[columns] ;
```

**In Printing Array**

Change this

```
for(int row = 1; row < figures.length; ++row) {    
    group = (char)((row-1)+(int)'A');
```

to

```
for(int row = 0; row < figures.length; ++row) {    
    group = (char)((row)+(int)'A');
```

**In display function**

Change this

```
for(int row = 1; row < x.length; ++row) {    
    group = (char)((row-1)+(int)'A');
```

to

```
for(int row = 0; row < x.length; ++row) {    
    group = (char)((row)+(int)'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's this

```
        for(int j = 0; j <= columns; j++) {
            figures[j] = new double[j] ;
        }
```

I think you meant actually

```
        figures[t] = new double[columns];
```

Comment: The change actually did not effect the output. The original problem still remains.

Comment: And you replaced the first with the second?

Comment: Yes I have replaced the original segment of code with your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: This is how rows should be initialised, make sure you don't miss anything: for(int t = 0; t < rows; t++) {
   rLetter = (char)((t)+'A');
   System.out.print("Please enter number of positions in row " + rLetter + " : ");
   columns = Keyboard.nextInt();
   Keyboard.nextLine();

   while((columns < 0) || (columns >= 8)) {
    System.out.print("ERROR:Out of range, try again              : ");
    columns = Keyboard.nextInt();
    Keyboard.nextLine();
   }
   figures[t] = new double[columns];
  }

Comment: Its partially fixed, but now the code produces an extra row when the table is generated. An input of 3 rows with 2,1,3 will give the correct column length now but an extra column at the end is generated.